# MongoError: command aggregate requires authentication

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, google-cloud-functions, mongodb-atlas

When connecting to mongodb atlas from firebase functions I'm randomly getting following error. Any idea what's causing this(it seems to get fixed automatically without any intervention)?

```
{ 
MongoError: command aggregate requires authentication
at queryCallback (/user_code/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:248:25)
at /user_code/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:532:18
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1540073032 },
ok: 0,
errmsg: 'command aggregate requires authentication',
code: 13,
codeName: 'Unauthorized',
'$clusterTime': 
{ clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1540073032 },
signature: { hash: [Object], keyId: [Object] } },
name: 'MongoError' 
}
```

Comment: I assume you've checked the authentication that the error is alluding to?

Comment: This happens randomly. If I redeploy firebase functions, it gets fixed most of the time. What happens is application is working fine for some time and then suddenly these errors begin to appear which effectively halts every operation which relies on DB.

Comment: I am getting the same error message. Got no clue how to proceed with this. For some reason this only happens when I use .aggregate()

Answer (score 0):

I was facing something similar. Turns out when I was using the tunnel to run the code on local, it wont work on server. So it was a silly mistake. Check if no other instance of your mongodb is in use.